# How can I use class-dump to get the headers of IOHIDLib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

It can dump the runtime headers of private frameworks of iOS by `class-dump` tool. but I'm looking for the headers of the `IOHIDEvent` which has been moved to any where that I can not find after iOS 6. But, in the iOS 6 SDK there is lib looks like it:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin

How can I dump the headers of the IOHIDLib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class-dump` is a tool that lets you reverse engineer **Objective-C** binaries.  But, it looks to me like `IOHIDLib` is a C/C++ library, so class-dump won't help you there:

```sh
$ class-dump -H IOHIDLib 
2013-06-14 02:55:39.104 class-dump[4676:707] Unknown load command: 0x0000002a
2013-06-14 02:55:39.106 class-dump[4676:707] Unknown load command: 0x0000002b
2013-06-14 02:55:39.109 class-dump[4676:707] Warning: This file does not contain any Objective-C runtime information.
```

Luckily, `IOHIDEvent` appears to be part of the open-source part of iOS.  You can find [headers (and .cpp file) for it here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDFamily-368.13/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDEvent.h).

I don't know what you're trying to do with it, but if it's some basic touch event handling, you might try using `GSEvent`.  There's a good bit more documentation for that, especially if you search on stackoverflow.

Comment: Is there any way to dump the headers of c/c++ library?

Comment: Not exactly.  You can do some reverse engineering, though.  An expensive tool like `IDA Pro` would do it, or a cheap one like `Hopper Disassembler`.  Objective-C is sort of special in how easy it is to reverse engineer binaries that aren't encrypted.