# How to capture and record iOS Touch Events at system level?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak

I want to capture all the touch events at the system level, I do not mean capturing at one specified app, but all the apps even the SpringBoard.I tried IOHIDEvent(https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/tree/master/IOKit/hid), but the runtime headers was changed after iOS4, and now I can not get them of iOS6.
May be GSEvent is also a good way, but does anyone known how to do this by GSEvent?
Thank you!

Comment: I assume you realize this, given that you link to "reconstituted" private headers, but this is not intended to be possible, and code that does this would be unlikely to ever pass AppStore review, and thus would only be usable on jailbroken devices. (Oh, hey, look! You tagged it with `jailbreak` -- OK then, carry on.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at EntryDevLevel excellent answer here on how to capture and record clicks on iOS using iOHID:

[iOS touch event notifications (private API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537564/ios-touch-event-notifications-private-api/15550916#15550916)

BTW. His solution works on non jailbroken iOS either.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.The answer is indeed excellent, but it told about only how to capture events.I still don't known how to simulate clicks with IOHIDEvent while I know how to capture events with IOHIDEvent.And I don't known how to capture events with GSEvent while I known how to simulate clicks with GSEvent.

Comment: I believe you asked about simulation of events in different question (which is correct way - to separate out concerns and ask them as separate question. And as I saw Nate gave links to the answers how to simulate events.