# Injecting touch events on iOS

Tags: android, ios, touch

I'm developing an iOS application which is sharing it's screen with another device through socket connection. On the other device I handle the touch events and send the screen coordinates to the iOS app but I don't know how to inject them in order to do something. For example if I hold my finger on the screen on the other device and I send the screen coordinates I want the iOS application to act as if I hold my finger on it too. There's no need to do it on system-wide, only on my application.

In Android I used `sendPointerSync` but here I searched some other questions and I can't understand if it is possible on iOS too and if it is possible - how?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a simple approach here since Apple has (intentionally) kept the internal workings of generating events and touches private.

Comment: I found one solution but the man who wrote about it is saying that Apple would not approve it for AppStore.

Comment: Hi WWJD, what solution did you find? Can you post some more info?

Comment: Hi @huisinro! Refer to this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105027/how-can-i-simulate-the-touch-events-by-iohidevent/17106232#17106232)